# Multiple cab extraction simultaniously

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writing cab extraction utility, I written cab utility which is working fine for single cab extraction.

I want solution in which I will allow user to select cab folder which may contain multiple cab files.
According to that I want to add that many progress bar control  to wpf window and I want to extract cabs parallal basis

Please suggest solution

Comment: Which part you have problem? We have no idea how to do that without your code. If `Extract` is a method, then call the method in multiple threads? Assuming method doesn't access any shared data, otherwise synchronization is required.

Comment: I want to dispaly progress of extraction on wpf UI, I stuch here only, i.e. not understanding how to add progress bar dynamically on UI and bind them to paricular cab extraction properties i.e percentage completed, file being extracted etc.